# can we set multiple attributes in servlets

Tags: java, servlets

We can get multiple attributes by using `getAttributeNames()`,
but I can't set multiple attributes by using `setAttribute()`. I will try to like this code but it doesn't work. Please check this and is there any chance for multiple attributes to be set or not?

```
public class First extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        try{
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();
            ServletContext context=request.getServletContext();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

            Enumeration en=request.getParameterNames();  
            while(en.hasMoreElements()){
                String str=(String)en.nextElement();

                String param=request.getParameter(str);
                System.out.println("names...."+str+".......values...."+param);

                session.setAttribute("cnr", param);
```

Comment: You can store multiple attributes, but what I see here is you're trying to set it in session variable, are you sure you need that through the session, you can also set the attributes using request.setAttribute(attrName, attrValue) but if you need it from through the next request.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think best is session.setAttribute(param
, param);

Comment: It's working fine now.Thank you for giving valuable information.

Comment: Hi Devireddy, have you applied my suggestion if yes please give me some points.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dynamically construct your attribute name. Every time you are overwriting the attribute name cnr with new value.

you need to perform something like below

```
int i = 0;
while(en.hasMoreElements()){

 session.setAttribute("cnr"+i, param);

 i++;
}
```

Comment: it's working fine.Thank you for giving your  valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Below line will be executed in loop and one "cnr" can't store multiple values. Either you have to change name dynamically so that multiple session will create to store multiple value or you have to use any other way like using request.setAttribute (If you need value while sending request).

Hope, it may helps you to solving your issue.

```
session.setAttribute("cnr", param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `key` needs to be unique, so this line `session.setAttribute("cnr", param)` will override the previous attributes with key `cnr`, if any.

Instead you use:

```
session.setAttribute(str, param);//`str` must be unique
```